# Help debugging sql query: where do I have an extra ( or )?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting 2 errors:
   1) Incorrect syntax near keyword union
   2) Incorrect syntax near ')'

Here is the query:

```
select count(*) as numUsers, count(r.cabGroupId) as numCompanies from
            (select r.newUserId, r.groupId
            from reportaccesslogs r full outer myTable d
            on r.num = d.num
            where (r.reportId = 1) and (r.groupId not in (666, 999))
            and ((r.num1 = @num1)) or (d.num1 = @num1))

            union

            select userId, groupId 
            from detailsLog
            where (num1 = coalesce(@num1, num1)) and (num2= @num2) and (num3= coalesce(@num3, num3)) 
            and (groupId not in (666, 999))) tmp
```

Comment: You may want to clarify what you want.  Do you want to do the first select from the unioned tables as a subquery, or the first select from the subquery unioned with the second select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select count(*) as numUsers, count(r.cabGroupId) as numCompanies 
from
            (select r.newUserId, r.groupId
            from reportaccesslogs r full outer myTable d
            on r.num = d.num
            where (r.reportId = 1) and (r.groupId not in (666, 999)
            and ((r.num1 = @num1) or (d.num1 = @num1)))

            union

            select userId, groupId 
            from detailsLog
            where (num1 = coalesce(@num1, num1)
            and (groupId not in (666, 999)))) tmp
```

See if that works.

Comment: Note - this will combine your two unioned queries.  I am assuming you want to use that as the data set for the  counts.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you have an extra ')' in last line beside tmp